# SSIS Project - Foreach loop through Package Parameter

Tags: excel, ssis

I am new to SSIS Package Development. I have to develop this for importing over a thousand of excel files. I can successfully import them but I have one thing to ask.

Here is my problem.

I want to specify the excel directory in SSIS Package Parameter and loop all the excels.

[image]

As Shown in picture. I can successfully loop through and import all excels by using `FilePath_2` which is fixed path. That was totally works. But I can't use this fix path. Customer wants to import his folder path on his own computer.

I tried to change using `FilePath_1` which is link with Package `Parameter` but `Foreach loop` import same file (10-302.xls) again and again.

Here is my rest setup.

Package Parameters
[image]

Excel Connection Manager

[image]

Foreach loop Variable Mapping
[image]

Am I getting wrong direction? I can't find any information like that on google.

Please guide me thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined FilePath_1 and are providing conflicting values for it.

1. It has an Expression which sets the value to be the Package Parameter `FilePath`
2. You have a Foreach File Enumerator looping over some folder (not shown) and are assigning the results to FilePath_1. That value is assigned, but the expression from #1 has precedence and the evaluated value returns to #1.

Create a variable called ImportPath and use as its expression the package parameter FilePath. This should be a root path to find files like, `C:\folder1\folder2`

Strip the expression from FilePath_1 and things ought to be working.

Comment: Thanks. You mean I just need to use `FilePath_1` variable as a fix path and `Package Parameter (root path)` used as a expression in `Foreach Loop`.

Comment: Only reason I'd look to creating a variable to hold the parameter value (and use the variable in the Foreach container is that ... it feels like _something_ couldn't pull in parameters but maybe it was something else in the SSIS ecosystem (or I'm imagining it). At any rate, my general pattern is to create local variables that receive project/package parameters but it's just a pattern.